# Заполнение формы в зависимости от выбранного option

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Здраствуйте! Имеется форма, которая должна заполняться из бд в зависимости от выбранного option.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Был бы вам крайне благодарен за помощь.

```html
<select>
<option></option>
<select><br>

<input type="file" placeholder="photo"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="name"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="pisition"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="info"><br>
<input type="number" placeholder="experience"><br>
```

Comment: видимо тебе надо на select повесить jquery обработчик, который отправляет данные на сервер, а полученные данные прописывает в эти поля.

Comment: К сожалению хоть и понимаю его, но шибко не работаю с ним

Comment: Видимо мы не так поняли друг друга

Comment: @Kugasu у вас трудности с чем-то конкретным возникли? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Прошу сильно не критиковать, поскольку недавно начал его изучать.
У меня не совсем получается передать значения из бд в select-option с последующим выводом их в input. 
Т.е. если в option выбран пункт с id 2, то выводится соответствующая строка из бд.
По задумке это упростило бы администратору изменение статьи

Comment: предоставь код, в котором "не совсем получается", без кода мы не можем помочь, мы не видим его телепатически.